# Facebook login javascript sdk TypeError

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to setup Facebook login for my website, and am receiving the following error (but only when I am not logged into Facebook in a separate tab):
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null 
on the following line:

```
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
```

I am using the JS code from:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2

Any suggestions as to what this is? I see no mention of creating a DIV with an ID of status in the docs.

Thanks.

Comment: post all the code in a jsfiddle.

Comment: `<div id="status"></div>` is right in the code that you linked to.

Comment: yeah, I worked out the issue, thanks